# Failed building wheel for turi create on windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, turi-create

I am trying to install turi create on windows (windows7) for use in Python 2.7. I am operating in a virtual environment, have updated pip and setup tools but keep getting an [image: error message]. Which states "pip install did not find any available binary package for your system"; as well as additional text including "
Failed building wheel for turicreate...Running setup.py install for turicreate...error"

Answer (score 0):

According to Pypi, turicreate only supports:

- macOS 10.12+
- Linux (with glibc 2.12+)
- Windows 10 (via WSL)

you can find more on [here](https://pypi.org/project/turicreate/#description) or on https://github.com/apple/turicreate

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ubuntu for windows. I am not sure this is available for windows 7. But it is available for windows 10.

Another option is to use online services like paperspace or crestle. I have tried crestle with turicreate and it works.